# PDO Connection SSL Certificate pem

Tags: php, pdo, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, pem

I have this request:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=37.48.33.333;dbname=dbname', 'user', '***********', array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    =>'cert1.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT   =>'cert2.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA     =>'cert3.pem'
   )
);
```

I follow the instruction on this page: https://serverfault.com/questions/306345/certification-authority-root-certificate-expiry-and-renewal

but I can't connect to DB, have this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on ....

2 weeks ago this function works, so I think is a problem of Certificates, but I'm not sure.

Is there a more specifical procedure to generate key, certificate and CA files to connect?

Comment: have you tried putting absolute path to .pem files? What error do you receive?

Comment: Yes, I write cert1.pem to not show real path, the error returned is a Mysql error, I try Also without certificates but not work

Comment: " I can't connect to DB" - What exactly prevents you from doing it?

Comment: put the error into the question

Comment: I suggest you add `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` to your array and make sure your PHP development box is configured to display error messages. Please ask for details is you need help on this, don't just ignore the tip.

Comment: I detect the error by try-catch with PDOException

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this kind of connections but "Can't connect to MySQL server" suggests it isn't even reaching the server at physical level. Did you configure MySQL Server for SSL?

Comment: Yes, it's the configurated. Last week all function works correctly, I do not modified any code. So this is why I Think at certified problems.

Comment: Check permissions to your certificate file. This could be the issue.